# Regex: Delete the content of all files that doesn't have this word/tag

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I have this tag/words:

`text text`

`text <Arlechino> text`

`text text`

So, I know how to delete the content of all files that have this tag: `(?s)(.*?(<Arlechino>)).*$`

The problem is the inverse, how to delete the content of the files that doesn't have this tag. Anyway, I can do this easily by search the files and select those that doesn't have this tag.

But I need a regex.

Short: if the regex finds the tag  do nothing. If doesn't find the tag, will delete the entire content of file.

Comment: Which language are you using to do the job? Add an appropriate language tag

Comment: `^(?!.*<Arlechino>).*` in addition to checking *dot matches newline* option

Comment: WORKS if I check .matches newline ! But if I have something linked by `<Arlechino>`, like `bla<Arlechino>` it does the same. So It has to be unique search.

Comment: So what are your requirements exactly?

Comment: hello, revo. As I said, if the regex finds `<Arlechino>`, leave the content of the files alone. If it find it, delete all the content - so the file be empty.

Comment: You said `bla<Arlechino>` shouldn't be matched. Why and what do you mean by unique search? As long as the string has `<Arlechino>` in it whether or not followed by or preceded by a character it is supposed to be deleted.

Comment: @revo: `^(?!.*<Arlechino>).*` does not work in Notepad++ because `^` matches the beginning of a line by default (and there is no way to redefine this behavior). See the correct answer below.

Comment: If `^(?!.*<Arlechino>).*` worked, I'd close as a dupe of the well-known SO post.

Comment: It works actually. Also please what are the differences between [**`^(?!.*<Arlechino>).*`**](https://regex101.com/r/emU9YR/1) and [**`\A(?!.*?<Arlechino>).*`**](https://regex101.com/r/emU9YR/2) with `dot matches newline` option on in Notepad++ (note: `m` flag is set due your comment)? The answer is nothing. So you posted the same solution with changing some meta-characters and quantifiers with their alternatives which match exactly the same thing. Even it doesn't denote a more optimal solution. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @revo: I only close *evident* dupes. When I am not sure, I never close questions. Please stop posting personal comments, this is not the proper place. You are always welcome at [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I'm waiting for you reply about my last but one comment. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @revo: The answer for that one is that you are wrong and `\A` and `^` match different things in NPP regex. See [Npp regex syntax docs](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: That's why I set `m` flag in regex101 live demos to simulate NPP regex engine. Please what's the difference. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Do not use regex101 to test NPP regex. NPP regex is powered with Boost (actually, with some peculiarities), and regex101 only supports PCRE/Python/Js. as I always note: **test the regex solutions in the target environments only**.

Comment: Please, I know what I'm talking about. You claimed it doesn't work. [**Wrong it is.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVmQ3.png). Please note when `s` modifier is set, `^` matches at the very beginning of first line of input string then steps into next pattern which is a lookahead with a greedy dot `.*` inside. Since `s` modifier is set, greedy dot consumes all characters then backtracks. Caret `^` is never going to be matched at any position again so here it denotes exactly a *beginning of input string* `\A` meta-character. All of these words are documentary. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Great, now try using OP text with the same regex and settings.

Comment: What do you mean by OP's settings? What settings? I'm not sure what does that *^ zero length match* do there but what is obvious is [it doesn't match anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSpHk.png). @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ok, I did it for you. [This is what your solution does with OP text](http://imgur.com/a/voJyc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, to perform such a search and replace operation on the *whole document*, you need to use

```
(?s)\A(?!.*?<Arlechino>).*
```

Or, if you have a list of keywords that must be matched as whole words but they can start with non-word characters, use

```
(?s)\A(?!.*?(?<!\w)(<Arlechino>|Word1)(?!\w)).*
            ^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^
```

where `(?<!\w)` fails the match if the keyword is preceded with a word char, and `(?!\w)` fails the match if the keyword is followed with a word char (effectively working as unambiguous word boundaries).

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - enables dot to match newline
- `\A` - start of the document
- `(?!.*?<Arlechino>)` -  a negative lookahead that checks if there is a `<Arlechino>` substring after any 0+ chars and if found, the match is failed
- `.*` - the rest of the document up to its end.

[image]

Comment: Can you make a match case for search? Because there is only one problem, Wiktor. Supose, instead of `<Arlechino>` I have an word like `spell`. Well, `spell` is different from `spelling` in many ways. So, if I want to delete all files that hasn't `spell` your regex will not delete also the files that has `spelling`. So, you understand my concern. It has to be an match case for what I want to search.

Comment: To match a whole word `spell`, use `\bspell\b`. [See more details on word boundaries here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: works. thanks. Please modify your answer and add this second solution.

Comment: Well, I cannot find any mention of a "whole" / "entire" word in your question. Let it remain in the comment. Note you cannot use `\b<Arlechino>\b`, because that will only match if `<Arlechino>` is enclosed with word chars.

Comment: I don't speak english very well. But you've realized what I mean. Anyway, please can you modify a little bit you regex, so I can search anything with or without symbols like `<>*&^$%` . Because if I try to put `\b <Arlechino>\b` in your regex, right now doesn't work. Because of the symbols `<>`

Comment: When you use `<word>`, do not use `\b`. If you use `word`, use `\b`. Maybe you can avoid this by just using `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` instead of the  `\b` whose meaning is context dependent. Something like `(?s)\A(?!.*?(?<!\w)Arlechino(?!\w)).*`

Comment: Works. Thanks. `(?s)\A(?!.*?(?<!\w)Arlechino(?!>\w)).*`

Comment: I edited the post a bit to also show how this can be used with a use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138855/discussion-between-just-me-and-wiktor-stribizew).